# Meta Tags appearance in <body> in Spring Java application

Tags: spring-roo

We are developing a Java web app in Spring 3.4.0. In Jspx files we are entering meta tags in  section but when rendered in browser they appear in . Does any one know the root cause? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

< section > is an HTML5 tag, you must add the < !DOCTYPE > declaration, and it must be the very first thing in your HTML document, before the < html > tag. Note older browsers don't know HTML5 and don't render HTML5 tags.